# OpenGL double buffers on Ubuntu does not work

Tags: linux, opengl, buffer

I'm testing out several of Sumantha Guha's code and there's something that isn't working quite right... All of the sample code where he uses GLUT_DOUBLE and glutSwapBuffers() does not work on my ubuntu machine, but works on my Windows machine. More accurately the window that pops out simply traces the background.

[image]

I've had this issue before on Windows where Flush and single buffers don't work, but now this is happening on Linux where Double buffers and glutSwapBuffers do not work. Any idea as to what may be causing this?

Sample of code that I tried loading. Compiles fine, just get a window that traces the background.

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// loadTextures.cpp
//
// This stripped-down program shows how to load both external and program-generated images as textures.
//
// NOTE: The Textures folder must be in the same one as this program.
//
// Interaction:
// Press the left and right arrow keys to rotate the square.
// Press space to toggle between textures.
// Press delete to reset.
//
// Sumanta Guha
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////
// TEXTURE GREDITS:
// canLabel.bmp, thanks anonymous.
// canTop.bmp, thanks www.acoustica.com.
// cray2.bmp, thanks NASA website www.nasa.gov.
// grass.bmp, thanks www.amazingtextures.com.
// launch.bmp, thanks NASA website www.nasa.gov.
// nightsky.bmp, thanks anonymous.
// sky.bmp, thanks www.mega-tex.nl.
// trees.bmp, thanks anonymous.
////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#ifdef __APPLE__
#  include <GLUT/glut.h>
#  include <OpenGL/glext.h>
#else
#  include <GL/glut.h>
#  include <GL/glext.h>
#endif

using namespace std;

// Globals.
static unsigned int texture[2]; // Array of texture indices.
static unsigned char chessboard[64][64][3]; // Storage for chessboard image.
static float angle = 0.0; // Angle to rotate textured square.
static int id = 0; // Currently displayed texture id.

// Struct of bitmap file.
struct BitMapFile
{
   int sizeX;
   int sizeY;
   unsigned char *data;
};

// Routine to read a bitmap file.
// Works only for uncompressed bmp files of 24-bit color.
BitMapFile *getBMPData(string filename)
{
   BitMapFile *bmp = new BitMapFile;
   unsigned int size, offset, headerSize;

   // Read input file name.
   ifstream infile(filename.c_str(), ios::binary);

   // Get the starting point of the image data.
   infile.seekg(10);
   infile.read((char *) &offset, 4); 

   // Get the header size of the bitmap.
   infile.read((char *) &headerSize,4);

   // Get width and height values in the bitmap header.
   infile.seekg(18);
   infile.read( (char *) &bmp->sizeX, 4);
   infile.read( (char *) &bmp->sizeY, 4);

   // Allocate buffer for the image.
   size = bmp->sizeX * bmp->sizeY * 24;
   bmp->data = new unsigned char[size];

   // Read bitmap data.
   infile.seekg(offset);
   infile.read((char *) bmp->data , size);

   // Reverse color from bgr to rgb.
   int temp;
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 3)
   { 
      temp = bmp->data[i];
      bmp->data[i] = bmp->data[i+2];
      bmp->data[i+2] = temp;
   }

   return bmp;
}

// Load external textures.
void loadExternalTextures()         
{
   // Local storage for bmp image data.
   BitMapFile *image[1];

   // Load the texture.
   image[0] = getBMPData("Textures/launch.bmp"); 

   // Activate texture index texture[0]. 
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]); 

   // Set texture parameters for wrapping.
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

   // Set texture parameters for filtering.
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

   // Specify an image as the texture to be bound with the currently active texture index.
   glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, image[0]->sizeX, image[0]->sizeY, 0, 
            GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image[0]->data);
}

// Routine to load a program-generated image as a texture. 
void loadProceduralTextures()           
{
   // Activate texture index texture[1]. 
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[1]); 

   // Set texture parameters for wrapping.
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

   // Set texture parameters for filtering.
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

   // Specify an image as the texture to be bound with the currently active texture index.
   glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 64, 64, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, chessboard);
}

// Create 64 x 64 RGB image of a chessboard.
void createChessboard(void)
{
   int i, j;
   for (i = 0; i < 64; i++) 
      for (j = 0; j < 64; j++) 
     if ( ( ((i/8)%2) && ((j/8)%2) ) || ( !((i/8)%2) && !((j/8)%2) ) )
         {
        chessboard[i][j][0] = 0x00;
        chessboard[i][j][1] = 0x00;
        chessboard[i][j][2] = 0x00;
         }
         else
         {
        chessboard[i][j][0] = 0xFF;
        chessboard[i][j][1] = 0xFF;
        chessboard[i][j][2] = 0xFF;
         }
}

// Initialization routine.
void setup(void)
{    
   glClearColor(0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.0); 

   // Create texture index array.
   glGenTextures(2, texture); 

   // Load external texture and generate and load procedural texture.
   loadExternalTextures();
   createChessboard();
   loadProceduralTextures();

   // Turn on OpenGL texturing.
   glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

   // Specify how texture values combine with current surface color values.
   glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE); 
}

// Drawing routine.
void drawScene(void)
{
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

   glLoadIdentity();
   gluLookAt(0.0, 0.0, 20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
   glRotatef(angle, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0); 

   // Activate a texture.
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[id]);        

   // Map the texture onto a square polygon.
   glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
      glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(-10.0, -10.0, 0.0);
      glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(10.0, -10.0, 0.0);
      glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(10.0, 10.0, 0.0);
      glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(-10.0, 10.0, 0.0);
   glEnd();

   glutSwapBuffers();   
}

// OpenGL window reshape routine.
void resize(int w, int h)
{
   glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h);
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity();
   glFrustum(-5.0, 5.0, -5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 100.0);
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glLoadIdentity();
}

// Keyboard input processing routine.
void keyInput(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
   switch(key) 
   {
      case 27:
     exit(0);
     break;
      case ' ':
     id++;
         if (id == 2) id = 0; 
     glutPostRedisplay();
     break;
      case 127:
         angle = 0.0; 
     glutPostRedisplay();
     break;
      default:
     break;
   }
}

// Callback routine for non-ASCII key entry.
void specialKeyInput(int key, int x, int y)
{
   if (key == GLUT_KEY_LEFT) 
   {
      angle -= 5.0;
      if (angle < 0.0) angle += 360.0;
   }
   if (key == GLUT_KEY_RIGHT) 
   {
      angle += 5.0;
      if (angle > 360.0) angle -= 360.0;
   }
   glutPostRedisplay();
}

// Routine to output interaction instructions to the C++ window.
void printInteraction(void)
{
   cout << "Interaction:" << endl;
   cout << "Press the left and right arrow keys to rotate the square." << endl
        << "Press space to toggle between textures." << endl
    << "Press delete to reset." << endl;
}

// Main routine.
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
   printInteraction();
   glutInit(&argc, argv);
   glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
   glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
   glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
   glutCreateWindow("loadTextures.cpp");
   setup();
   glutDisplayFunc(drawScene);
   glutReshapeFunc(resize);
   glutKeyboardFunc(keyInput);
   glutSpecialFunc(specialKeyInput);
   glutMainLoop();

   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: OpenGL implementation? Code?

Comment: @larsmans included a sample that I tried running (code by Guha)

Comment: I know it's an old post but I got the same problem, do you rememebr how have you solved that?

Comment: I wish I did, this was from school I barely remember opengl anymore, sorry.